# Conditional breakpoint not working

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, conditional-breakpoint

[image: Conditional Dialog]

The above code has a conditional breakpoint set at its bottom line in yellow followed by the Breakpoint Settings dialog which should work with:
item.Value == "aday"

However I get the below error, I have searched online for this and can't find any reason why this should fail.  Im using VS 2015 Pro.

[image]

EDIT-  Thank you for pointing out the obvious error on my part, I do normally code in C#.
But now using a single '=' I get this???????
I assume that I it equates to an assignment, and adding parenthesis didn't help either?

[image]

Comment: Use .Equals() instead of =/==.

Comment: One additional hint: conditional breakpoints tend to have a bad performance. Use `If item.Value = "aday" Then Debugger.Break()` instead like shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/535822/2882256)

Comment: @ilansch  I got an error with .equals I'm afraid, not sure but possibly because Im in strict mode.  If I add a code breakpoint like my below answer then it works fine, thank you very much

Comment: @AndrewDay were you able to solve this ? I am using C# and I get your second error => "The breakpoint condition must evaluate to a boolean operation". My condition is "myVar != null" and it fails :(

Comment: @Gonzalo.-  My solution is at the bottom, I have marked it as correct now. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If item.Value.Equals("aday") Then 'Temp If please remove
                    Debugger.Break()
                end if
```

Works in strict mode.

Answer (score 13):

Just tested with a sample VB.NET project.
The problem is the `==`. This is C# syntax but since you have a VB.NET application you should use a single equal

```
item.Value = "aday"
```

(I have always something new to learn from SO)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the C# in Visual Studio 2017.

After search in an hour, conclusion was:

rewrite the conditional expression from:

```
item.Value == "aday"
```

to:

```
item != null && item.Value == "aday"
```

MAKE SURE item was not null. so that you can refer to field of value with `item.Value`