# Conditional breakpoint not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I have an issue debugging my C# code in Visual Studio 2015.

I want to add a simple expression into a breakpoint,

So I added `hierarchyRelation != null` as condition. That is a local variable of the method I am debugging, and it exists.

However, in runtime I get the following error

> "The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute. The condition was
>   "hierarchyRelation != null". The error returned was "The breakpoint
>   condition must evaluate to a boolean operation". Click OK to stop at
>   this breakpoint.

Actually, the condition was more complex, but this is the simplest case that reproduces the problem. I tried variants, and even comparing properties of this variable and it always fails the same.

If I try a constant condition, like `1 != 2` or `1 = 1` it works fine. Is there any issue ? The closest related question I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479548/conditional-breakpoint-not-working), but it was in `vb code`. Its solution was to add a debug method directly in the code. Although I can do that, I want to know why is this not working.

The method code

```
private HierarchyNodeDto GetNodeTreeThatContainsText<TRollup, TLeaf, THierarchyRelation>(HierarchyNodeDto root, string text, PreFilter preFilter, Func<TLeaf, bool> leafContainsTextFunc, bool parentContainsText) where TRollup: HierarchyNodeDto where TLeaf: HierarchyNodeDto {
            dynamic rootNode = root as TRollup;
            if (rootNode != null) {
                if (rootNode.Nodes == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                var childNodesWithText = new List<THierarchyRelation>();
                foreach (var hierarchyRelation in rootNode.Nodes) {
                    var isLeaf = hierarchyRelation.Node.GetType() == typeof(TransactionTypeHierarchyLeafDto) || hierarchyRelation.Node.GetType() == typeof(AccountHierarchyLeafDto);
                    if (!isLeaf && hierarchyRelation.Node.Name != null && hierarchyRelation.Node.Name.ToLower().Contains(text) && preFilter != PreFilter.Leafs) {
                        childNodesWithText.Add(hierarchyRelation);
                        continue;
                    }
                    var subtreeThatContainsText = this.GetNodeTreeThatContainsText<TRollup, TLeaf, THierarchyRelation>(hierarchyRelation.Node, text, preFilter, leafContainsTextFunc, rootNode.Name.ToLower().Contains(text));
                    if (subtreeThatContainsText == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    hierarchyRelation.Node = subtreeThatContainsText;
                    childNodesWithText.Add(hierarchyRelation);
                }
                rootNode.Nodes = childNodesWithText;
                if (rootNode.Nodes.Count > 0 || (rootNode.Name.ToLower().Contains(text) && preFilter != PreFilter.Leafs)) {
                    return rootNode;
                }
                return null;
            }
            var rootLeaf = root as TLeaf;

            return rootLeaf != null && ((leafContainsTextFunc.Invoke(rootLeaf) && preFilter != PreFilter.Nodes) || (parentContainsText && preFilter != PreFilter.Leafs)) ? rootLeaf : null;
        }
```

I am adding the breakpoint in the first line inside the `foreach`

[image]

Comment: The VS2015 debugger does have rather a lot of bugs, but this doesn't look broken when I try it.  Be sure to have the updates installed, at least up to Update 2.  Possible workarounds are avoiding the bugs with Tools > Options > Debugging > General, "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" and "Use the legacy C# and VB.NET expression evaluators".

Comment: I have installed Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. Will try to check that compatibility mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the `hierarchyRelation` is a dynamic variable although I'm not totally sure why. According to [Expressions in the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za56x861.aspx#Anchor_3) it should work (I couldn't find a reason why it shouldn't) .

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic foo = new Foo();

        // conditional breakpoint 'foo.Nodes == null' here
    }

    internal class Foo
    {
        public IEnumerable<Foo> Nodes = null;
    }
```

This code triggers the same exception whenever the debugger passes and evaluates the conditional breakpoint. Statically typing the `foo` variable will make the debugger able to evaluate the expression and break whenever needed.

Comment: ok so it looks like it is a VS bug ? Will try to remove the dynamic to see if it works

Comment: Yes this seems to be a problem with the debugger although I cannot confirm this.

Comment: I updated the very same code to using a statically typed class and worked just fine. It seems it is a bug in dynamic then. will wait to see if someone comes up with a solution to make this work with dynamic, otherwise I will set your answer as correct. Deserved upvote in the meantime

Comment: It most definitely is a bug. Imo the variable should not be dynamic at all because it seems to me it is not contextual at all. The type, `TRollup`, is known so I would type it implicitly by using `var`. I could be missing a technical detail that forces it to be dynamic though (although you said it worked fine without dynamic :P)

Answer (score 8):

A bit late to the party but anyway, I hit the same problem like this as well, with a dynamic object too.

What I did to solve this was to cast it as an object in the breakpoint's conditional expression itself; so in your case, doing the following would work:

```
(object)hierarchyRelation!=null
```

Give it a go and see if that works out for you.

Comment: thanks ! But I do not work in that company nor with that technology anymore.. Have your upvote though

Comment: My case was a simple integer local variable, checking for 'x = 106'. Had to explicitly cast x as integer in breakpoint condition to get it to work. No such thing as too late to the party with useful stuff like like this...

Comment: For VB.net users the comment by @saminpa is relevant if the variable is default Object type, you need to put cint(x) = 106, or declare the variable type.  Can't believe I've known and not used this feature for maybe 8 years because VS was complaining that  x = 1 didn't evaluate to boolean, even though it clearly does.